# I can not log in with the basic user and password

Tags: login

When I start up my raspberry pi I get the color thing, and then when it says recovery I sometimes pressed it and sometimes didn't. Please tell me if I should or not.

Anyway I get to the login screen and type the user *pi* and the password *raspberry*. After that it goes black and looks like it will work, but then it goes straight back to the login screen.

I'm using the Default Xsession and my ethernet, HDMI and charger cables are all plugged in. My microSD card is in and I have barely worked on the pi before this, so that shouldn't be a problem.

What do I need to do?

Comment: The most likely problem is lack of power.  Try a different power supply.

Comment: I had this exact issue when my sd card went bad.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tightvnc installed and have it starting at boot?

I had a similar problem and to fix it you need to make the *pi* user the owner of .Xauthority

```
chown pi:pi .Xauthority
```

Reboot and you should now be able to log in.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Linux generally. I too ran into it once.
This might help:https://askubuntu.com/q/223501/553855

And if it doesn't, use an *older* image of Raspbian and flash that.